# Runtime error in dynamically allocating 2D array in C

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to dynamically allocate a 2D array, put some values, and print output. However it seems that I am making mistake in getting input to program in atoi() function.

Basically when we assign a static 2D array, we declare it as say int a [3][3]. So 3*3 units if int, that much memory gets allocated. Is same thing holds for allocating dynamic array as well?

Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(int arg,char* argv)
{
int rows = atoi(argv[1]);
int col = atoi(argv[2]);

int rows =3;
int col=3;
int i,j;

int (*arr)[col] = malloc(sizeof (*arr)*rows);

int *ptr = &(arr[0][0]);
int ct=1;
for (i=0;i<rows;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<col;j++)
    {
        arr[i][j]=ct;
        ct++;
    }
}   

printf("printing array \n");
for (i=0;i<rows;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<col;j++)
    {
        printf("%d \t",arr[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}   

free(arr);

return (0);
}
```

Program crashes in runtime. Can someone comment?

Comment: I ran program as: array 3 3

Comment: Although it's not an answer to the exact question, I wouldn't use two-indexed arrays. In the end, it's just contiguous memory. Something like `int *arr = malloc(sizeof(int) * row * col);  arr[r * row + c] = ...` would be equivalent to `arr[r][c]`.

Comment: Change your decl to `int (*arr)[col] = malloc(sizeof(*arr) * rows)`. *Everything* else should work as-is. If you're wondering why that works, consider how `int *p = malloc(sizeof(*p) * 10);` works, and later how you can use `p[i]` to access the 10 values just allocated. This is no different. Only the underlying type has changed.

Answer (score 0):

The first issue I see is this line:

```
int (*arr)[rows][col] = malloc(sizeof (*arr) * rows);
```

This is not problematic at all because you are in fact allocating more memory than you need. This would suffice:

```
int (*arr)[rows][col] = malloc(sizeof (*arr));
```

`sizeof *arr` is enough because `*arr` is of type `int [rows][cols]`; the memory you want is exactly the size of that array. The `sizeof` operator, when applied to arrays, gives you the count for the whole array.

The main problem with your code, however, is how you use `arr`. You are indexing it with `arr[i][j]`, but instead, you should be using `(*arr)[i][j]`, because `arr` is *not* an array, it's a pointer to an array. You need to dereference it before any further indexing - as simple as that. `arr[i][j]` is equivalent to `*(*(arr+i)+j)`. Note that `i` should be an offset into `*arr`, not an offset on `arr`. That's why you need to dereference `arr` before indexing.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already using variable-length arrays, you may take advantage of that:

```
int (*arr)[col] = malloc(sizeof *arr * rows);
```

This way you can simply access elements with the usual syntax `arr[i][j]` without worrying about pointers and dereferences, pointer arithmetic will do all the work for you.

Also since indexes start from 0 your tests should look like `i < rows` and `j < col`.
And you have some minor errors for the wrong `main` declaration and the second `printf`.

Comment: I modified first line as int (*arr)[col] = malloc(sizeof (*arr)*rows); and second printf statement as printf("[%d][%d] \t",arr[i][j]); and fixed for loop equalities. Still program crashes at runtime.

Comment: @user35197339 have you corrected the main declaration?